# Create new OneNote notebook from template with filename using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onenote

I'm currently in a use case that I need to create a new OneNote notebook on SharePoint from a template notebook.

I'm coding in Java (web) and for the moment I have this code :

```
Clients.evalJavaScript("(new ActiveXObject('SharePoint.OpenDocuments'))."
            + "CreateNewDocument2("
            + "window, "
            + "'http://some.url/sites/Demo/DocLib/Forms/Document/Note.onepkg',"
            + "'http://some.url/sites/Demo/DocLib);");
```

This works **but** the user has to give a name in a popup what opens. Now I need to create the filename by myself.

If I check the [OpenDocuments documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc264170(v=office.14).aspx), I don't see a method for setting the name by myself.

So the next one I tried was this :

```
Clients.evalJavaScript("(new ActiveXObject('SharePoint.OpenDocuments'))."
            + "CreateNewDocument2("
            + "window, "
            + "'http://some.url/sites/Demo/DocLib/Forms/Document/Note.onepkg',"
            + "'http://some.url/sites/Demo/DocLib/Forms/bbb.onepkg');");
```

This code didn't show the popup for creation **but** I'm working on the template and the `bbb.onepkg` isn't created.

I hope someone has already had this issue and can give me the direction on how I can implement this.

Comment: Do those ActiveXObjects work in Chome, Firefox, or even Microsoft Edge?

Comment: I'ts an intranet application. We use default is IE zo thats no problem